# using mid function and how to tell excel to return the number of character/numbers to return is until a text string is found

Tags: excel-formula

I have excel cells with cell values of below examples..

```
029763812ZAZMEX/S13K330000DG6T190/CONSOL
29763812ZAZMEX/S13K436L6T190/CONSOL
```

What i need is to extract numbers just after "K" and before any other text ("DG" or "L") appears.

the results needed are;

```
330000    
436
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this array fromula:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("K",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),MIN(SEARCH({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"},MID(A1,FIND("K",A1)+1,LEN(A1))&"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))-1)
```

Being an array formula is needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Another note, I got tired entering the alphabet and stopped after `"L"`.  You will need to extend the array to the whole alphabet.

Also add any other characters you want to end the number string, ie `"/"`.  It will need to be added to the array and the part at the end.

[image]

Comment: you will need store the alphabet array in note pad for quick copy and pasting for answers.

Comment: @nuruedriss Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Upper left corner of the answer, under the down triangle. @nuruedriss